# How to get the reverse percentile for a list of scores from a huge txt file?

Tags: python, r, pandas, awk, scipy

I have a very big text file (>80Gb). It contains tab-delimited values. I am interested only in one column. For that specific column, I want to get the [reverse percentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) for ~10 thresholds. So basically, my questions look like this: "What is the percentage of rows where the value of column x is below $threshold?". Thresholds are roughly 1, 5, 10, 100, 500, 1000.
Sample data:

```
   dontcare dontcare interesting
   1        10       502
   2        10       0
   3        10       100
   4        10       23
   5        10       5
```

In the above case, I would like to ask "What is the percentage of values below 500?" and the answer would be 80%.

How would I do this?

Notes:

- Using awk to filter the file first for the interesting column took ~26mins which is fine speed-wise (ended up with a file <10Gb).
- Reading the resulting file into a pandas data frame takes ~7 mins; but the calculation (`df[df < threshold].shape(0) / total_length`) takes way too long. I stopped calculations after a couple of hours. I guess ~1h would be okay.
- `wc -l <filename>` and `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None); print(pandasdataframe)` yielded a different number of rows which astonished me. (I'm new to Pandas, though).
- I'd prefer a solution in Python/Shell but I'm open for any ideas.

**EDIT:**

The answer below is correct. I came up with the script below. FYI, reading the prefiltered file (one column only, <10G) took 1h02 and reading the original file (5 cols, >80G) took 1h16. For the sake of simplicity, I won't prefilter the file then. mawk was 2x better than gawk in my tests. I used `NR` instead of `(NR-1)` as there is no header row.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
COL=$2 # one-based
AWK_CMD=mawk
THRESHOLDS="0 5 10 20 50 100 200 300 400 500 1000"

[ "$#" -ne 2 ] && { echo >&2 "usage: $0 <filename> <one-based-col>"; exit 1; }
# check if awk cmd exists
command -v $AWK_CMD >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Cannot find $AWK_CMD. Please install and/or put it into your \$PATH."; exit 1; }

# constuct final cmd
CMD="$AWK_CMD 'BEGIN { total=0;"
for t in $THRESHOLDS; do
    # set init vars to zero
    CMD="${CMD} n$t=0;"
done
CMD="${CMD}}; { total+=\$$COL}; "
for t in $THRESHOLDS; do
    # increment depending on threshold
    CMD="${CMD} {if (\$$COL>$t) {n$t+=1}} ;"
done
CMD="${CMD} END { print \"mean: \" total/NR; "
for t in $THRESHOLDS; do
    # output percentage
    CMD="${CMD} print \"above$t: \" n$t/NR*100 ;"
done
CMD="${CMD} }' $FILENAME"

# echo $CMD
eval $CMD # backticks and $() won't work here
```

Comment: This code should be fast enough: `awk 'BEGIN {n=0;getline}; {if ($3<500) {n+=1}} END {print n/(NR-1)*100}' x.txt`

Comment: @MaratTalipov What is the point of that begin block ?

Comment: @User112638726, to skip the header line

Comment: @MaratTalipov ahh okay, don't need the n=0 though. All variables are initialised at 0 anyway in awk.

Comment: @User112638726, yes, that's true.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit ...

Comment: No, explicit is NOT better than implicit. If it were we'd all be writing assembly code. Conciseness is an attribute of good software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using awk to do this:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $3 < 500 { ++n } END { if (NR > 1) print n / (NR - 1) * 100 }' file
```

For all lines after the first one where the third field is less than 500, increment `n`. Once the file has been processed, print the percentage, as long as one or more records have been read (this avoids a division by 0).